# Message vs ErrorMessage API design

Tags: api

I'm desing API for generic task executor that currently supports two calls:

1. Accept task
2. Get task info

The `(2)` provides detailed information about the task with the task status and custom message, for example in JSON format:

```
{
   ...
   status: "SUCCESS",
   message: "The task has been finished successfully"
   ...
}
```

In case of status `"ERROR"` do I need to have a separate field `"errorMessage"` or it's normal to write error message to field `"message"`? Technically any solution is possible, but I'm looking for the best practices, I didn't find any strict recommendations yet.

Comment: It kind of depends on how you plan on using the message, but generally when I do something like you want, I simply have a status and errorText field. If status is SUCCESS then there's no reason to fill in the message/errorText field. Saying the task finished successfully is redundant.

Comment: @Dunk I'm personally not planning to use it, but other people are going to use that API, that is why I'm interested about the best practice/expectation here. I like the idea to keep the errorText and just leave it empty in case there is nothing to report there, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...do I need to have a separate field "errorMessage"?

Only if you need to maintain *two separate messages* in any given JSON transaction.

Comment: I don't need to have two messages, I just need to provide more information what happened with the task, either successful or not successful.

Comment: Then it's one transaction, one message, one field.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get more mileage with a status/message pair than with a separate errorMessage property. For instance, if you wanted to write a general 'alert' function showing the job and its status, it will be a cleaner piece of code to use the status to determine colour, and always show the same 'message' property.